# How to filter event in a task-schedule?

Tags: task-scheduler

I have two event which both have the same EventID and is of type Warning, but I want to just send one of them. The other event occurs frequently which brings a lot of noise in the mailbox. How to filter out that? Is it possible?

Comment: Are both events from the same source? How are you filtering -- In `eventvwr`? In a script?  If a script, which language?

Comment: In Windows Server 2008 R2 and with the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the "Trigger" of your current task and change the Settings from "Basic" to "Custom".  Then click `New Event Filter...` and you can customize what you'd like to trigger based off of with more precision.

Your question is a bit unclear.  I can't tell if you have two events that have the same ID and **one** is of type "Warning" or you have two events of the same ID and **both** are of type "Warning".  If it's the former, this can be resolved by checking the box `Warning`, otherwise you'll have to create a custom XML filter.  If you provide a bit more information, I can assist you.

Comment: A custom XML filter is needed!

Comment: If you let us know what the differences between the two events you're trying to filter are, we can help you with that filter.  If you continue to hold all the details close to your chest, our hands are tied.